# Raspberry Pi Connected to CH340 on STM32F103. Broken Pi and USB interface

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, buck, arm

I have a 3D printer that's running based on a STM32 chip. Included on the mainboard is a CH340 serial to USB converter.

I connected this board with to my Raspberry pi 3 which I powered using the 24v PSU from the printer and steped it down to 5v using a cheap buck converter.(you might know where this is heading)

The buck converter is rated for 3A so it ran very hot when powering the Raspberry pi and I realized it when the hot glue I applied on the back of it started to drip. I immediately cut the power but It did quite some damage. **So my first question is, what happens when a buck converter gets overheated, will it output a higher voltage?**

My Pi still runs but the LAN9514 Ethernet and USB hub chip runs extremely hot instantly, so I plan on de-soldering it and see how it goes, but as of now, the system seems to boot alright.
The STM32 board also still runs but the **data lines of the USB from the CH340 are broken**. I am sure that it's only the data lines because I used masking take to cover the 5v and GND connections on the USB cable, it was to prevent the GND from the USB powering the 3d printer since they were running off of the same PSU.

I am not sure what happened and I was wondering if replacing the CH304 and LAN9514 chips alone could revive these two boards?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So between two devices, you connected USB data lines only, leaving 5V and ground disconnected? Powered from same power supply, but how was the power connected?

Comment: Right, so my mains voltages goes into the PSU which outputs 24v DC. One connection goes to the STM32 board which has a onboard regulator. The buck converter is parallel to the STM32 board which takes in 24v and outputs 5v and goes into the Raspberry Pi.
The USB cable from the STM32 to the Raspberry Pi only has the data lines because If I don't cover the power lines and turn off the power to the STM32, the raspberry pi tries to power it via USB.

Comment: which specific STM32 board it is? If custom, post schematics. Which cheap buck converter you use? Are the grounds of the STM32 board and RPi firmly connected so there is no voltage difference between them?

Comment: Specifically it's the Creality3D printer v4.2.2 board. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the schematics but many are asking for it on their repo, so hopefully we get something soon. What I can try to do is bypass the USB-Serial interface and connect the TX/RX pins directly with a external interface, but the vias on the PCB are very thin so I am hesitant to do that.
The buck converter is based on a LM2596 chip and is only rated for 3A. 
There should be no voltage difference between the RPi and STM32 GND since they are technically in parallel , connected on the same GND terminals on the PSU.